# Gradient of $X^{T}AX$ wrt matrix X

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to calculate the gradient of $X^{T}AX$ with respect to $X$, where $X$ and $A$ are $nxn$ matrixes. Using the matrix cookboox [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf) (pag 9), I see that the gradient is obtained for each element $ij$ of $X$ denoted by $X_{ij}$ as 
$$X^{T}AJ_{ij}+J_{ij}AX$$
where $J_{ij}$ denotes the single-entry matrix with a $1$ at position $ij$ and $0$ elsewhere. However,I find that for each element $X_{ij}$ the resulting partial derivative is a matrix, so that the gradient of the whole $X$ would be a set of matrixes. Which in my head seems strange. Could anyone help on this?

Comment: What is $X$ ? An $1\times n$ vector ?

Comment: Shouldn't the result be a tensor of rank 4? for each combination of indices $i,j$ of the input $X$ and $a,b$ of the outpu $X^T A X$, you get a value.

Comment: @GabrielRomon they are all matrixes, sorry I didn't specify, I have edited to mirror your coment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index notation might help you see what's going on.
$$\eqalign{
F &= X^TAX \\
F_{il} &= \sum_{j}\sum_{k} X_{ij}^TA_{jk}X_{kl}
 &= X_{ji}A_{jk}X_{kl} \\
}$$
where the last expression uses the summation convention, i.e. the sigma's are implicit rather than explicit for repeated indices. It also drops the superscript indicating the transpose, instead the order of the indices is swapped.

The next thing to note is that the gradient of a matrix with respect to *itself* can be written in terms of [Kronecker deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial X_{kl}}{\partial X_{mn}} &= \delta_{km}\delta_{ln} \\
}$$
Putting these two things together, you can calculate the gradient 
$$\eqalign{
G_{ilmn} &= \frac{\partial F_{il}}{\partial X_{mn}} \\
&= (\delta_{jm}\delta_{in})A_{jk}X_{kl} + X_{ji}A_{jk}(\delta_{km}\delta_{ln}) \\
&= \delta_{in}A_{mk}X_{kl} + X_{ji}A_{jm}\delta_{ln} \\
}$$
and see that it requires 4 indices, instead of the two indices that are required for a matrix. 

Thus the name *fourth-order tensor*.

Comment: thanks a million greg! Many many thanks